# Down-convert Visual C# 2008 Professional to Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have been working on a project in Visual Studio 2008 Professional, and I recently tried to open it up on a computer with Visual Studio 2008 Express and four of the six projects were unavailable as Visual Studio puts it. I don't understand why, I am not using openMP or plugins. Just my code, some [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA), and a couple of libraries like [EasyStorage](http://easystorage.codeplex.com/).

Am I stuck? I thought there would be an automatic conversion. I also couldn't ever get others to help me on my projects if it requires them to buy Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2010 Professional...

Answer (score 1):

Where did the missing projects live on your computer?  Look in your solution file, and make sure you don't have an odd project reference to a location (directory, mapped share) that doesn't exist or isn't accessible on your target computer.  Something like:

```
Project("{...}") = "Proj1", "..\..\..\temp\proj1.csproj"
```